# How to create custom alerts with log analytics query by using ARM templates

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-log-analytics, azure-alerts

I am working on to create the alerts in azure for various azure resources using ARM templates. But I want to create custom alerts for Azure Data Factory by using below log analytics query:

> "alertLogQuery": "ADFPipelineRun\r\n| where ResourceId has 'df-xxx-xxx-xxxx'\r\n| where  TimeGenerated > ago(15m)\r\n| where  Status has 'Queued'\r\n| where  PipelineName in ('pl_xxx_Business_xxx_Check' , 'pl_xxx_xxxx_Date_Check')\r\n| summarize by  PipelineName, TimeGenerated\n",

Template file:

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "isEnabled": {
        "type": "bool",
        "defaultValue": true,
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Specifies whether the alert is enabled"
        }
    },
    "rgNameOfActionGroup": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The resource group name of the action group"
        }
    },
    "actionGroupName": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The name of the action group"
        }
    },
    "rgNameOfLogAnalyticsWorkspace": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The resource group name of the log analytics workspace"
        }
    },
    "logAnalyticsWorkspaceName": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The name of the log analytics workspace"
        }
    },
    "alertTypes": {
        "type": "array",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "An array that contains objects with properties for the metric alerts."
        }
    }
},
"variables": {
    "actionGroupResourceId": "[concat('/subscriptions/',subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', parameters('rgNameOfActionGroup'), '/providers/Microsoft.insights/actionGroups/', parameters('actionGroupName'))]",
    "workspaceResourceId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', parameters('rgNameOfLogAnalyticsWorkspace'), '/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/', parameters('logAnalyticsWorkspaceName'))]",
    "copy": [
        {
            "name": "alertTypes",
            "count": "[length(parameters('alertTypes'))]",
            "input": "[parameters('alertTypes')[copyIndex('alertTypes')].alertName]"
        }
    ],
    "alertSource": {
        "Type": "ResultCount"
    },
    "alertEvaluation": {
        "Frequency": 15,
        "Time": 15
    },
    "alertActions": {
        "SuppressTimeinMin": 20
    }
},
"resources": [
    {
        "copy": {
            "name": "alertTypes",
            "count": "[length(parameters('alertTypes'))]"
        },
        "name": "[parameters('alertTypes')[copyIndex('alertTypes')].alertName]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules",
        "apiVersion": "2018-04-16",
        "location": "global",
        "tags": {},
        "properties": {
            "description": "[parameters('alertTypes')[copyIndex('alertTypes')].alertDescription]",
            "enabled": "[parameters('isEnabled')]",
            "source": {
                "query": "[parameters('alertTypes')[copyIndex('alertTypes')].alertLogQuery]",
                "dataSourceId": "[variables('workspaceResourceId')]",
                "queryType": "[variables('alertSource').Type]"
            },
            "schedule": {
                "frequencyInMinutes": "[variables('alertEvaluation').Frequency]",
                "timeWindowInMinutes": "[variables('alertEvaluation').Time]"
            },
            "action": {
                "odata.type": "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Monitoring.Alerts.Models.Microsoft.AppInsights.Nexus.DataContracts.Resources.ScheduledQueryRules.AlertingAction",
                "severity": "[parameters('alertTypes')[copyIndex('alertTypes')].alertSeverity]",
                "throttlingInMin": "[variables('alertActions').SuppressTimeinMin]",
                "aznsAction": {
                    "actionGroup": "[array(variables('actionGroupResourceId'))]",
                    "emailSubject": "[parameters('alertTypes')[copyIndex('alertTypes')].alertName]"
                },
                "trigger": {
                    "thresholdOperator": "[parameters('alertTypes')[copyIndex('alertTypes')].operator]",
                    "threshold": "[parameters('alertTypes')[copyIndex('alertTypes')].thresholdValue]",
                    "metricTrigger": {
                        "thresholdOperator": "[parameters('alertTypes')[copyIndex('alertTypes')].operator]",
                        "threshold": "[parameters('alertTypes')[copyIndex('alertTypes')].thresholdValue]",
                        "metricColumn": "Classification",
                        "metricTriggerType": "Consecutive"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
],
"outputs": {
    "alertNames": {
        "type": "array",
        "value": "[variables('alertTypes')]"
    }
}
  }
```

I'm getting the below error:

> Template validation failed: The template resource 'df-xx-xx-xxx-Queued Demo ADF pipelines alert/report' for type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Frontdoor.Common.Entities.TemplateGenericProperty`1[System.String]' at line '71' and column '60' has incorrect segment lengths. A nested resource type must have identical number of segments as its resource name. A root resource type must have segment length one greater than its resource name.

So, can anyone suggest me how to fix the above issue.

Comment: Take a look at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-log-create-templates#simple-template-up-to-api-version-2018-04-16).

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-log-create-templates#simple-template-up-to-api-version-2018-04-16). In the `variables` -> `alertSource` section, you can add your custom alert rule there:

```
"alertSource":{
            "Query":"write your query here",
            "SourceId": "xxxxx",
            "Type":"xxxx"
        },
```

Note that you need to escape some characters like `""` in your query if it has.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, Can you please provide sample script which contains the log analytics query of data factory.

Comment: @Pradeep, I see you've already written the query in your question. so what help do you need? how to put the query there, or the query is not correct(it's just a demo)?

Comment: Ivan, Please look at my updated question once.

Comment: @IvanYangCould you please assist me on the problem i'm facing as i've posted here:     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67336508/creating-dashboard-using-kusto-query-in-arm-template-format