# Creating Dashboard using Kusto query in ARM Template format

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-log-analytics, kql

Hope you all are doing good.
I've working on Kusto query which runs against Azure Kubernetes cluster. it works fine though when i try to incorporate within ARM template to create dashboard it throws me an error related to "expected token 'RightParenthesis' and actual 'Identifier'".

Running query in log analytic workspace is given below:

```
let clusterName = 'AKS';
Perf
| where TimeGenerated > ago(2m)
| where ObjectName == "K8SNode" 
| where CounterName == "cpuAllocatableNanoCores" 
| where InstanceName contains clusterName
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by Computer
| summarize TotalCores=sum(CounterValue), x="join"
| join kind = inner (
    KubePodInventory
    | where TimeGenerated > ago(2m)
    | where ClusterName contains clusterName
    | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by ContainerName
    | project Name, ContainerName, Namespace
    | join kind = inner (
        Perf
        | where TimeGenerated > ago(2m)
        | where ObjectName == 'K8SContainer'
        | where CounterName == 'cpuUsageNanoCores'
        | where InstanceName contains clusterName
        | extend ContainerNameParts = split(InstanceName, '/')
        | extend ContainerNamePartCount = array_length(ContainerNameParts)            
        | extend PodUIDIndex = ContainerNamePartCount - 2, ContainerNameIndex = ContainerNamePartCount - 1 
        | extend ContainerName = strcat(ContainerNameParts[PodUIDIndex], '/', ContainerNameParts[ContainerNameIndex])
        | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by ContainerName
        | project ContainerName, CounterValue
        )
        on ContainerName
    | project Name, Namespace, CounterValue
    | summarize CoresPerNamespace=sum(CounterValue) by Namespace, x="join"
    )
    on x
| project UtcTime=now(), Namespace, CpuUtilizationPerNamespace=(CoresPerNamespace / TotalCores) * 100
```

**==========================**

Later i tried to incorporate this with in ARM template and it throws an error.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "dashboardName": {
      "defaultValue": "AKS-Temp-Dashboard",
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "DASHBOARD name for Azure kubernetes service cluster"
      }
    },
    "resourceGroupName": {
      "defaultValue": "aks-rg",
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Azure resourceGroup name for Azure kubernetes service cluster"
      }
    },
    "aksClusterName": {
      "defaultValue": "aks",
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Azure kubernetes service cluster name"
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
    "dashboardName": "[concat(parameters('dashboardName'), '-DASHBOARD')]",
    "aksResourceId": "[resourceId(parameters('resourceGroupName') , 'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters', parameters('aksClusterName'))]"
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "lenses": {
          "0": {
            "order": 0,
            "parts": {
                "1": {
                "position": {
                  "x": 0,
                  "y": 3,
                  "colSpan": 5,
                  "rowSpan": 3
                },
                "metadata": {
                  "inputs": [
                    {
                      "name": "resourceTypeMode",
                      "isOptional": true
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "ComponentId",
                      "isOptional": true
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "Scope",
                      "value": {
                        "resourceIds": [
                          "/subscriptions/7777t-a1ae-4ca9-89bc-gfgf7577575/resourcegroups/rg-eus/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/aks""
                        ]
                      },
                      "isOptional": true
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "PartId",
                      "value": "4ae7fd78-1a4f-4025-a091-7d57e08d6822",
                      "isOptional": true
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "Version",
                      "value": "2.0",
                      "isOptional": true
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "TimeRange",
                      "isOptional": true
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "DashboardId",
                      "isOptional": true
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "DraftRequestParameters",
                      "isOptional": true
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "Query",
                      "value": "[concat('let clustername = \"', parameters('aksClusterName'), '\"; Perf\n| where TimeGenerated > ago(2m)\n| where ObjectName == \"K8SNode\" \n| where CounterName == \"cpuAllocatableNanoCores\" \n| where InstanceName contains clusterName\n| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by Computer\n| summarize TotalCores=sum(CounterValue), x=\"join\"\n| join kind = inner (\n    KubePodInventory\n    | where TimeGenerated > ago(2m)\n    | where ClusterName contains clusterName\n    | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by ContainerName\n    | project Name, ContainerName, Namespace\n    | join kind = inner (\n        Perf\n        | where TimeGenerated > ago(2m)\n        | where ObjectName == 'K8SContainer'\n        | where CounterName == 'cpuUsageNanoCores'\n        | where InstanceName contains clusterName\n        | extend ContainerNameParts = split(InstanceName, '/')\n        | extend ContainerNamePartCount = array_length(ContainerNameParts)            \n        | extend PodUIDIndex = ContainerNamePartCount - 2, ContainerNameIndex = ContainerNamePartCount - 1 \n        | extend ContainerName = strcat(ContainerNameParts[PodUIDIndex], '/', ContainerNameParts[ContainerNameIndex])\n        | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by ContainerName\n        | project ContainerName, CounterValue\n        )\n        on ContainerName\n    | project Name, Namespace, CounterValue\n    | summarize CoresPerNamespace=sum(CounterValue) by Namespace, x=\"join\"\n    )\n    on x\n| project UtcTime=now(), Namespace, CpuUtilizationPerNamespace=(CoresPerNamespace / TotalCores) * 100\n\n ')]",
                      
                      
                      "isOptional": true
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "ControlType",
                      "value": "FrameControlChart",
                      "isOptional": true
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "SpecificChart",
                      "value": "StackedColumn",
                      "isOptional": true
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "PartTitle",
                      "value": "Analytics",
                      "isOptional": true
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "PartSubTitle",
                      "value": "gaks-la1",
                      "isOptional": true
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "Dimensions",
                      "value": {
                        "xAxis": {
                          "name": "UtcTime",
                          "type": "datetime"
                        },
                        "yAxis": [
                          {
                            "name": "CpuUtilizationPerNamespace",
                            "type": "real"
                          }
                        ],
                        "splitBy": [
                          {
                            "name": "Namespace",
                            "type": "string"
                          }
                        ],
                        "aggregation": "Sum"
                      },
                      "isOptional": true
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "LegendOptions",
                      "value": {
                        "isEnabled": true,
                        "position": "Bottom"
                      },
                      "isOptional": true
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "IsQueryContainTimeRange",
                      "value": true,
                      "isOptional": true
                    }
                  ],
                  "type": "Extension/Microsoft_OperationsManagementSuite_Workspace/PartType/LogsDashboardPart",
                  "settings": {}
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "metadata": {
          "model": {}
        }
      },
      "name": "[variables('dashboardName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Portal/dashboards",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {
        "hidden-title": "AKS-Monitoring-Dashboard"
      },
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01-preview"
    }
  ]
}
```

Kindly assist me to sort out this issue.
NOTE: TO me it looks concat() function generating an issue.

Find an error screenshot below:

[image]

**Note:** Seems Concat() function is not setup correctly.

*****Adding Update running query after struggling a lot so that end users can take help *****

```
 "[concat('let clustername = \"', parameters('aksClusterName'), '\"; Perf \r\n| where TimeGenerated > ago(2m) \r\n| where ObjectName == \"K8SNode\" \r\n| where CounterName == \"cpuAllocatableNanoCores\" \r\n| where InstanceName contains clustername \r\n| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by Computer \r\n| summarize TotalCores=sum(CounterValue), x=''join'' \r\n| join kind = inner (\r\n    KubePodInventory \r\n    | where TimeGenerated > ago(2m) \r\n    | where ClusterName contains clustername \r\n    | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by ContainerName \r\n    | project Name, ContainerName, Namespace \r\n    | join kind = inner (\r\n        Perf \r\n        | where TimeGenerated > ago(2m) \r\n        | where ObjectName == ''K8SContainer'' \r\n        | where CounterName == ''cpuUsageNanoCores'' \r\n        | where InstanceName contains clustername \r\n        | extend ContainerNameParts = split(InstanceName, ''/'') \r\n        | extend ContainerNamePartCount = array_length(ContainerNameParts)            \r\n        | extend PodUIDIndex = ContainerNamePartCount - 2 \r\n| extend ContainerNameIndex = ContainerNamePartCount - 1 \r\n        | extend ContainerName = strcat(ContainerNameParts[PodUIDIndex], ''/'', ContainerNameParts[ContainerNameIndex]) \r\n        | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by ContainerName\r\n        | project ContainerName, CounterValue\r\n        )\r\n        on ContainerName\r\n    | project Name, Namespace, CounterValue\r\n    | summarize CoresPerNamespace=sum(CounterValue) by Namespace, x=''join''\r\n    )\r\n    on x \r\n| project UtcTime=now(), Namespace, CpuUtilizationPerNamespace=(CoresPerNamespace / TotalCores) * 100')]"
```

Comment: What is the error you get? in general to make it simple, you can create a function on the Log Analytics workspace and simply call the function from the dashboard.

Comment: @Avnera I've added a screenshot of an error. Kindly see it.

Comment: Looks like it is an arm template error, so you should ensure that the expression is valid based on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-expressions . As I said in the comment above, instead of putting the full query text in the arm template you should create a function in Azure Log analytics and call it from the template

Comment: Actually I will be creating the dynamic dashboard, each time i've to create new function for various customer in that case.Same concept works for other queries but it throws an error for this only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your KQL query you have apostrophes (eg `where CounterName == 'cpuUsageNanoCores'\n`) that you didn’t escape. ARM treats them as and of string and expects a comma and another parameter of concat function, hence the error. AFAIR you escape apostrophes with another one: `''`.

Comment: Yes, I found the same as an issue. Though thanks for answering it means a lot @Miq